# check if there are non-letters or non-numbers in the string

Tags: php, regex, string, validation

How can I detect a non number or non letter on a string?

`KY4R5EHCN5W476XXO5ER` - return `true`

`KY4R5EHCN5W472X**@**O5ER` - return `false`

I know the answer is to use a regular expression, I just don't know how to do it. I suck at regular expressions.  Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ctype_alnum()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) will be quite faster than a regular expression in detecting if a string is purely alpha-numeric (letters and numbers).

```
$str1 = 'KY4R5EHCN5W476XXO5ER';
$str2 = 'KY4R5EHCN5W472X*@*O5ER' ;

foreach (array($str1, $str2) as $str){ 

    if (ctype_alnum($str)) {
        echo "$str is alphanumeric\n" ;
    }
    else {
        echo "$str is not just alphanumeric\n";
    }
}
```

However, be sure to play with the regular expressions given here because it's a useful skill to have, especially if you later decide you also need to check for other characters like dashes. You will find [The Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/) very useful when experimenting with them.

```
$str = 'KY4R5EHCN5W476XXO5ER' ;
$ut = microtime(true) ;

for ($i = 0 ; $i < 100000; $i++) {
    $res = ctype_alnum($str) ;
}

$utCtype = microtime(true) ;

for ($i = 0 ; $i < 100000; $i++) {
    $res = preg_match('/[a-z0-9]/i', $str) ;
} 

$utEnd = microtime(true) ;

$utDiffCtype = $utCtype - $ut ;
$utDiffPreg = $utEnd - $utCtype;

echo "ctype: $utDiffCtype, preg: $utDiffPreg" ;
```

Comment: Interesting comparison.  The conclusion is, performance difference between the 2 methods negligible.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (preg_match('/[^A-Z0-9]/', $string)) {
    ... some char other than A-Z, 0-9 detected
}
```

Comment: you need the `i` on the end or you won't get the lower case characters.

Comment: or just add a-z to the character class. No lower case letters in the OP's samples anyways.

Comment: Yep, either way will work. In the OP, he just said `detect a non number or non letter`, even though the example only had caps.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (preg_match('/[^a-z0-9]/i', $subject)) {
    // Invalid characters
} else {
    // Only letters and numbers
}
```

Comment: You can simplify the class to just `^a-z0-9` since you're using `i` on the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex to be unicode compatible:

```
/^[\p{L}\p{N}]+$/u
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if (preg_match('/^([a-z0-9]+)$/iu', $string))
{
   // all alpha and digits
}
else
{
   // not all alpha and digits
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Maybe I should learn regular expression now cause its kinda cool. thanks again

Comment: @LeysamRosario Glad to help you (just like everyone who answer your question too)

Answer (score 0):

```
(preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9]+$/', $string) == 0)
```

change to a-zA-Z0-9 if you want to include lowercase characters

this should return true if the string contains only A-Z and 0-9.

or

```
(preg_match('/[^A-Z0-9]/', $string) != 0)
```

should do pretty much the same.